# set the limits of integration of the spherical coordinates between two paraboloids and a plane

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Find the volume of the solid $\mathcal{S}$ enclosed laterally by the paraboloids $\mathcal{P}_1$ of equation $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ of equation $z = 3(x^2 + y^2)$ and from above by the plane $z = 1$ using spherical Coordinates. How one may set the limits of integration of the spherical coordinates?

Now, for a solid bounded below by paraboloid $z=a^2(x^2+y^2)$ for $a>0$, and above by plane $z=1$, the volume can be obtained and it is equal to $\dfrac{\pi}{2a^2}$. Using this result we can get the volume of the solid $\mathcal{S}$ and obtain that
$$
V(\mathcal{S})=V_{\mathcal{P}_1}-V_{\mathcal{P}_2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2 \times 1}-\dfrac{\pi}{2\times 3}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}.
$$
But, how one can obtain the volume of $S$ using spherical coordinates?

Comment: There is formula for substitution in integral with spherical coordinates (https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/tisphericalcoords.aspx), though in your case seems more appropriate using cylindrical coordinates. Limits for spherical/cylindrical can be found by substitution in correspondence Cartesian limits.

Comment: @zkutch I know it can be done easier using cylindrical, and also can be done in cartesian, but my question is how we can solve it using spherical coordinates. In this tutorial link, I know the info there, but not related to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two components of the integral that must be considered:

1. When $\rho$ varies between the inner and outer paraboloid
2. When $\rho$ varies between the inner paraboloid and the plane $z=1$.

We consider these cases separately.

First, we transform the boundary surfaces into spherical coordinates. $z=1$ becomes $\rho \cos\phi = 1$, so $\rho = \sec \phi$. For $z = x^2 + y^2$, we have $\rho \cos \phi = \rho^2 \sin^2\phi$, so $\rho = \cot\phi \csc\phi$. Similarly, for $z = 3(x^2 + y^2)$, we have $\rho = \frac{1}{3}\cot\phi \csc\phi$. These will form the bounds on $\rho$ in our triple integrals.

We now need to find the bounds on $\phi$. The plane intersects the inner paraboloid at the point $(r,z) = (1/\sqrt{3},1)$, where $r^2 = x^2+y^2$. Recalling that $z = \rho \cos \phi$ and $r = \rho \sin \phi$, we then have $\phi = \tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\pi}{6}$. Using a similar calculation for the outer paraboloid, we find this intersection at $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$. This range corresponds to case (2) and case (1) is given by $\phi\in[\pi/4,\pi/2]$ where we vary from the plane intersection with the outer paraboloid all the way down to the $xy$-plane.

We then have

$$
V = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{\frac{1}{3}\cot\phi \csc\phi}^{\sec \phi} \rho^2\sin\phi~\mathrm{d}\rho \mathrm{d}\phi \mathrm{d}\theta + 
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\frac{1}{3}\cot\phi \csc\phi}^{\cot\phi \csc\phi} \rho^2\sin\phi~\mathrm{d}\rho \mathrm{d}\phi \mathrm{d}\theta.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's firstly consider our figure only in first quadrant and at the end will multiply result on $4$.

Let me consider spherical coordinates
$$\begin{cases}x=r\sin\phi\cos\theta & \\
y= r \sin\phi\sin\theta & \\
z=r\cos\theta \end{cases}$$
Accordingly we have $0\leqslant r < \infty$, $\phi \in [0,\pi]$ and $\theta \in (0, 2\pi]$.

Paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$ gives $r=\frac{\cos\phi }{\sin^2\phi}$ and $z=3(x^2+y^2)$ gives $r=\frac{\cos\phi }{3\sin^2\phi}$. As expected they are not dependent on $\theta$, so, it takes all range in first quadrant $\left[0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$. Plane $z=1$, obviously become $r=\frac{1}{\cos\phi}$.

With respect to $\phi$ volume is divided in two parts: from $\frac{\pi}{6}$ up to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ where ray from origin firstly meet $z=3(x^2+y^2)$ and then plane $z=1$ i.e. we are between $r=\frac{\cos\phi }{3\sin^2\phi}$ and $r=\frac{1}{\cos\phi}$. And from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ up to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ volume is between $r=\frac{\cos\phi }{3\sin^2\phi}$ and $r=\frac{\cos\phi }{\sin^2\phi}$. So we obtain:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}d\phi\int\limits_{\frac{\cos\phi }{3\sin^2\phi}}^{\frac{1}{\cos\phi}}r^2\sin\phi dr+\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\phi\int\limits_{\frac{\cos\phi }{3\sin^2\phi}}^{\frac{\cos\phi }{\sin^2\phi}}r^2\sin\phi dr = \frac{\pi}{12}$$

multiplying it on $4$, as mentioned, gives $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

Let me say, that, perhaps, most natural way to calculate this volume is consider its projection, for example, on $OZY$ and consider body of rotation around an axis $OZ$.

(Having prepared my answer, I found someone else’s already given, but still decided to leave my own, firstly, so that the questioner knew that I did not leave it without attention and, secondly, the person who wished could choose the answer he liked more.)